# SVN How to get a list of affected files in a set of multiple changes

Tags: svn

I need to determine a list of all affected files for a given branch.

I know there's `svn diff -c a:b --summarize` and `svn log -v --stop-on-copy`.

My problem is that the branch I'm working on has been synced with trunk multiple times and I need to exclude those merges in order to get the **actual** affected files work has been done on in my branch.

Is there a neat way to either specify the list of all changes like `svn diff -c 1,2,3,4 --summarize` **or** to exclude the changesets of the merges?

Comment: If you were using git I would tell you to cherry-pick the "real" revisions (not merges) on detached HEAD so that you can get the code from the branch _alone_ and not the merges. Then you could do `git diff --name-status original-branch...HEAD` but....